# Alinhar elementos horizontalmente - Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Estou criando um menu responsivo que contém 3 partes: logo da empresa, links para dispositivos grandes, ícone de menu para dispositivos pequenos.

gostaria que em dispositivos mobile a logo seja alinhada no centro e o ícone de menu à direita.

Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="float-lg-left">
        <!-- logo -->
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block float-right">
        <!-- menu desktop -->
    </div>
    <div class="d-block d-lg-none float-right">
        <!-- icone mobile -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer com que a logo fique alinhada no centro em dispositivos md e menores?

Comment: Talvez isso possa te ajudar (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements), mas neste caso do link, você terá que criar algumas divs com a logo e irá por esses códigos do link, porém ele apenas esconderá ou mostrará o elemento em um lugar (left, center, right) conforme o aparelho utilizado, mas de forma estática, não fluida, como você deseja. Acho que dá pra utilizar desta forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara fiz um exemplo simples ele não usa CSS apenas o que é default do BS4. A ideia é a mesma que vc já usou, porém ele tem 2 logos, uma que só aparece no Mobile no meio da barra e os ícones a esquerda que só aparecem no mobile tb.

**OBS 1:** A navbar por default já tem `display:flex`, e `justify-content: space-between` então como são 3 itens um sempre vai ficar a esquerda, outro ao centro e o último a direita.

**OBS 2:** Vc não precisa das classes de `float` para alinhar

*Veja como ficou no exemplo abaixo, e mande exibir tb em "Página toda" para ver como fica em versão Desktop vs Mobile*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-info">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-block">Brand</a>
        <div class="d-block d-lg-none">
            <ul class="nav d-flex ">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-white" href=""><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-block d-lg-none">Brand</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar4">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar4">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Codeply</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```